# Повторение короткого слова/частицы дважды подряд ("вот он он" и т.п.)

Tags: лингвистика, фонология, звук

Недавно при разговоре с одним моим знакомым я заметил, что он изредка в своей речи повторяет некоторые короткие слова дважды, причём такое повторение не звучит неправильно, а, наоборот, даже как-то органично. Вот пример: «Если бы они они не…», и второй: «Если бы бы хотели…». Как мне кажется, такой повтор помогает ему «удлинить» звучание коротких слов, чтобы их употребление в устной речи не звучало «обрубленным», причём такие повторения он явно делает неосознанно.

Таких случаев на самом деле было больше, просто я не могу точно вспомнить, какие еще местоимения или частицы он так повторял дважды. Причём, что интересно, я вспомнил, что не только он использует в своей речи такие «повторы» — примеры похожих неосознанных повторений я слышал и раньше, но вот заинтересовался этим только сейчас.

Если бы кто-нибудь смог мне подсказать, как называется такой лексический феномен, я был бы очень благодарен.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Хезитация . Подробнее здесьhttps://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/prichiny-i-formy-proyavleniya-povtora-v-spontannoy-rechi/viewer

Comment: @V.V., в том-то и дело, что тут нет явной хезитации. В приведенной Вами статье есть пример, где человек говорит что-то вроде: "Эта девушка, которая... которая... которая в платочке!" —но тут явно видно размышление говорящего, которое он заполняет словом "которая", но в том случае, о котором писал я, в речи вообще нет никакой паузы. То есть говорящий не запинается на слове "они", а наоборот словно тянет его за собой дальше в речи, причем совершенно без каких-либо хезитаций. И в моем посте я также говорил о том, что такое повторение я слышал в речи только с короткими, односложными словами..

Comment: не могу подсказать по названию феномена и вообще впервые о таком слышу, но заметила, что в обоих примерах, которые вы привели, повторяются слова, которые по звучанию напоминают соседние: "они-они-не", "бы-бы-вы", может быть это связано? человек в процессе понял, что сказал два слова, которые звучат одинаково, и решил повторить одно из них, чтобы было понятнее, что это два разных слова?

Comment: вот он он?......

Comment: @Anixx ДА! Вот самый распространенный из таких повторов, о которых я хотел сказать, просто забыл именно про этот пример! Не знаете ли вы случайно, как такой феномен называется?

Comment: В сочетании со словом «вот» употр., как усилительное слово, между прочим и в том случае, если предмет речи выражен 1-м лицом личного местоим. http://feb-web.ru/feb/ushakov/ush-abc/15/us280701.htm?cmd=0&istext=1

Comment: @V.V. Не совсем, там речь идёт про местоимение 1-го лица, т. е. про фразу "Вот он я!"

Comment: А что он сам говорит, почему он повторяет слова?

Comment: @άνθρωπος ничего не говорит, когда я его спросил, он даже сначала не понял, про что я. По всей видимости он их не замечает. С тех пор, как этот пост был опубликован, я уже много раз слышал пример таких вот повторений по типу "вот он он", "где бы бы" и т.д., но до сих пор так и не выяснил, что это за лексический феномен...

Comment: Мне кажется очень интересным и правдоподобным, что он повторяет одно и то же слово, чтобы "растянуть его". Это не редкость в английском языке. Например, как правило мы не используем настоящее совершенное время, когда уточняем, когда что-то произошло: This morning *I have seen... Однако когда мы хотим подчеркнуть свое потрясение или другие сильные эмоции по поводу чего-то, что произошло в прошлом, простое прошедшее время оказывается слишком коротким, поэтому мы используем настоящее совершенное время, чтобы иметь больше слов для подчеркивания: This morning I HAVE SEEN...!

Comment: https://www.smissle.com/reference/present-perfect#h.o7red96jwdia

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you're talking about. Is there any chance you could record your own rendition of your friend's speech pattern and update the post with a link to it? Thank you!

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что в словосочетании "вот он он" (предполагая, что оно произносится с ударением только на "вот", а оба "он" безударные и практически сливаются: "вОт он-он") первый "он" относится к экспрессивному выражению "вот он", а второй "он" -- собственно, объект этого высказывания. Сравните: "вот он где", "вот оно что". "вот она загвоздка". Так что я бы сказал, что это не совсем повторение, просто объект совпал с последним словом предыдущего словосочетания...

Comment: @CocoPop наоборот, тут - наречие или частица, а не вводное и пунктуация должна выглядеть так: ".. причем(вводное), такое повторение не звучит неправильно, а наоборот даже как-то органично". Наоборот - частица усиливающее "даже", и противопоставления тут нет, потому что "не звучит неправильно" = звучит правильно. Союз "а" тут ошибка, потому что "звучит правильно И органично.

Comment: причём, такое повторение звучит правильно и наоборот даже, как-то органично. - вот такая пунктуация.

Comment: Либо это наречие которое кособоко относится вообще к союзу А или вроде того, входя в состав союза "а наоборот даже", тогда: причем, такое повторение не звучит неправильно, а наоборот даже как-то органично. Либо "причём" это не вводное, а союз и текст был написан правильно. Но после твоей коррекции, это точно неправильно)

Comment: Разницу между наречием, союзом и частицей можно попытаться понять тут: https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/422/наоборот

Answer (score 1):

> [...] как называется такой лексический феномен

Боюсь показаться Капитаном Очевидность, но общее название для любых повторов слов -- **[редупликация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)**. Но это очень широкий термин, под который подходят и полный, и неполный, и фонетический, и морфемный и лексический повтор: "зимушка зима", "трава-мурава", "чудо чудное", "дурак дураком", "думал думал и придумал", "ходил бродил", "тянут-потянут", "строили мы строили".

Судя по вопросу, говорящий использует этот приём, чтобы сакцентировать внимание на нужной ему части предложения. Получается, что это экспрессивная редупликация.

Поскольку повторяющиеся слова идут непосредственно друг за другом -- это уже **контактная экспрессивная редупликация**.

Гугл по запросу "контактный экспрессивный повтор в русском языке" находит несколько статей в профильных изданиях.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что это какая-то вырожденная или недоразвитая эпифора:

> (греч. epiphora из epi — после + phoros — несущий). Стилистическая фигура, противоположная анафоре, заключающаяся в повторении одних и тех же элементов в конце каждого параллельного ряда (стиха, строфы, предложения и т. д.). Мне бы хотелось знать, отчего я **титулярный советник**? Почему **именно титулярный советник**? (Гоголь).

То есть вместо того, чтобы составить параллельный ряд, он скупо повторяет одно и тоже слово, на котором хочет сделать акцент:

Вот он, он.

А мог бы: вот он, точно он, - тогда была бы эпифора.

В итоге эпифора скатывается в речевое "заикание".

Если бы они, они не… ~ если бы они, только они не...

Возможно, имеет место быть легкое нарушение речи. В любом случае, можно задать ему вопрос почему "бы-бы", а не просто "бы". Если он может ответить, то это он делает специально, а если нет - то это нарушение речи.